# Why doesn't my code that uses System.Xml.XmlReader detect an invalid XML file?

Tags: xml, xsd-validation, xmlreader

**Goal**

Using PowerShell 5.1, detect an invalid XML file by validating it against an XML schema using Microsoft's `System.Xml.XmlReader`. I'll detect the invalid XML file by catching the `XMLException` that `XmlReader` throws on an XML parse error.

Note: I don't want to use PowerShell Community Extensions `Test-Xml` cmdlet.

**The problem**

The line of code `$readerResult = $xmlReader.Read()` does not throw the XMLException I expect when parsing an invalid XML file

**References**

[Validation Using the XmlSchemaSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/as3tta56(v=vs.100))

[XmlReader Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=netframework-4.7.2#xmlreader_create)

**My XSD**

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="urn:config-file-schema">
  <xs:element name="notes">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="note" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="to"/>
              <xs:element name="from">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="type" use="optional"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="heading"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="body"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**My invalid XML (second line uses bogus element name `notXXXes`)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notXXXes xmlns="urn:config-file-schema">
    <note>
        <to>Tove</to>
        <from type="1">Jani</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    <note>
        <to>Bob</to>
        <from type="2">KeyW</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>I won't</body>
    </note>
</notes>
```

**My code**

When run, `$readerResult` returns true, indicating that the next node was read successfully. I  expect `$xmlReader.Read()` to throw an `XMLException` because the XML file content violates the schema.

```
cls
$error.clear()

try
{

    [System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet] $schemaSet = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet
    $schemaSet.Add("urn:config-file-schema","C:\Users\x\Desktop\test.xsd");

    [System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings] $readerSettings = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings
    $readerSettings.Schemas = $schemaSet
    $readerSettings.ValidationType = [System.Xml.ValidationType]::Schema
    $readerSettings.ConformanceLevel = [System.Xml.ConformanceLevel]::Fragment
    $readerSettings.IgnoreWhitespace = $true;
    $readerSettings.IgnoreComments = $true;

    [System.Xml.XmlReader]$xmlReader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create("C:\Users\x\Desktop\test.xml", $readerSettings);

    #just to show that Schemas was set up OK
    "target namespace: " + $readerSettings.Schemas.Schemas().TargetNamespace

    $readerResult = $xmlReader.Read()

    "readerResult: " + $readerResult
}
catch
{
    "error: " + $error
}
finally
{
    $xmlReader.Close()
}
```

**Edit #1**

This fragment will read each line of XML from file and display its metadata

```
while ($xmlReader.Read())
{
    write-console ("Depth:{0,1} Name:{1,-10} NodeType:{2,-15} Value:{3,-30}" -f $xmlReader.Depth, $xmlReader.Name, $xmlReader.NodeType, $xmlReader.Value)
}
```

Comment: And after that first `Read`, does it not indicate that all it's read so far is the XML Declaration, which looks to me like it's well formed?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  My mistake - I incorrectly thought that any one `Read` would validate the entire xml file against the xsd. I now understand that you need to `Read` a line from the xml file in order for that line to be validiated. Please state as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of the `XmlReader` concept is that it's a *streaming* approach to dealing with XML. This allows you to access large/complex XML documents without having to hold the entire thing in memory (and, if you're using DOM-style access, several layers of additional memory usage to boot).

This is efficient in terms of memory use, but does mean that errors are only reported as nodes with issues are encountered.

The first `Read` here reads the XML Declaration - `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` - which appears well formed and should not raise any errors. If you need to validate the entire document then you'll need to `Read` it entirely through until the end. But if that's your *only* purpose, I'd probably defer to e.g. the `Test-Xml` commandlet that you're dismissing.

Comment: Just to be clear: So, the minimum code required to read the entire document and so give the validator the opportunity to compare each piece of the xml to the schema is: `while ($xmlReader.Read()) {}`. Also, my intent is to validate the XML against the schema and then read the XML and perform processing on its values. I hesitate to use the `Test-Xml` cmdlet. I can't find it now, but I came across a S.O. Q&A where one of the answers described a particular scenario where `Test-Xml` failed to detect an invalid chunk of XML.

Comment: @NovaSysEng - I'd say process it once, doing whatever actual processing you need to do. But be ready for an error condition that comes along and tells you that the whole file isn't valid. So, where possible, avoid "committing" to further actions based on the XML (or have an "undo plan") until you've reached the end.